# CodeMirror: xml attribute completion, add = automatically

Tags: codemirror

Is it possible in CodeMirror to automatically add the = sign when autocompleting an attribute? Specifically on ctrl-space (like in the xml completion demo) when you almost finished typing the attribute's name and want to complete it using ctrl space...

Thanks,
Jaap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this
http://jsfiddle.net/aljordan82/h5f67/

```
   extraKeys: {
        "Ctrl-Space": function(){
          var cursor = editor.getCursor();
          var token = editor.getTokenTypeAt(cursor);
            //console.log(token)  
            if (token == "attribute"){ 
               editor.replaceSelection("=" , "end");
            }
        }
    }
```